May Jews remove nose hair or eyelashes during Sefirat Ha’Omer
According to Halacha, may Jews remove nose hair or eyelashes during Sefirat Ha’Omer, or no, do the semi mourning restrictions during this time not prohibit nose hair or eyelash removal? Or is this question a Machloket amongst the Poskim?

PTIJ: I think if they do that during the sefirah, it's a hefsek and they will need to make their own bracha.

Refer to this respons at Dinonline.org:

Essentially the minhag not to cut hair applies to all hair of the body and not only to facial hair. However it is permitted for a woman to tweeze unsightly hair such as from her eyebrows nose ears, as this is not considered taking a haircut. (In general for a man, it is not permitted even not during sefira because of lo tilbash).  A married woman may shave her legs if not shaving them will bother her husband.
Sources:
O:CH 551-12, Aruch Hashulchan ibid 31, Kovetz Halachos (Sefira) 10-1,2,  Hilchos Chag Bchag (Sefiras Haomer) 7-14 ftnt. 55, M:B 79, Y:D 182-1.


I had this in que since Erev Shabbos, I see that Eliyahu already linked to this article though.

Refer to here for leniencies.
